# Django-objects.get() get nothing and how to prevent it?

Tags: django

So I have checked several other question on stackoverflow but still can not find out why.

I just want to find out that if I can get the photo set by looking for its set_id. If there is nothing in the data base with this set_id I would Like to show a simple message on html.
I have the following code but when I have a non-existing set_id, it still try to do `code something else` and thus get an error.

I have also tried `if _set.exist()` and also `if not _set`, not working too.

```
    def msa_result(request, set_id):
        try:
            _set = PhotoSets.objects.get(set_id=set_id)
        except PhotoSets.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse("This set is not available")
    <code something else>
```

Comment: try setting the value of _set = NULL before the 'try' block inside the def msa_result and print the _set at the end of the 'try' block.
Tell me what value of _set is printed on your terminal. If its something other than NULL, then there exists a PhotoSet corresponding to that set_id
Check it and tell me the printed value

Comment: Thanks @AnkushRaghuvanshi  ! I figure out that I actually do have a set with that set_id, the problem is that there is no measurement in the set (foreign key model). And so this try-except stuff should be on another query and after 
I changed this, it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. :)
Printing the values on terminal whenever possible, is the best practice to use while you debug your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def msa_result(request, set_id):
     _set = PhotoSets.objects.get(set_id=set_id)
     if not _set:
        return HttpResponse("This set is not available")
     <code something else>
```

Comment: This won't work since the console will print "DoesNotExist: PhotoSets matching query does not exist."

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
def msa_result(request, set_id):
    try:
        _set = PhotoSets.objects.get(id=set_id) # -- change
    except PhotoSets.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse("This set is not available")
<code something else>
```